# displaying Unicode text from database to JTextArea

Tags: java, unicode, jtextarea

I have a database that has some text in multiple languages like English, Hindi, Telugu, Tamil, Marathi.

English and Hindi text is displayed perfectly. But when i choose other languages like telugu, tamil, it shows square boxes.

```
            JTextArea txtMessage = new JTextArea();
            txtMessage.setLineWrap( true );     
            txtMessage.setWrapStyleWord( true );
            JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(txtMessage);
            scrollPane.setBounds(93, 125, 226, 97);
            frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);


 lang = cbLanguage.getSelectedItem().toString();
 String sql2 = "Select message from messages where language = '"+lang+"';";
try {
    result = statement.executeQuery(sql2);
    while(result.next()){
        txtMessage.setText(result.getString(1));
    }
} catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

How do i make it display tamil and telugu fonts properly?

Comment: `Font font = ...some Unicode font...; txtMessage.setFont(font);`. Arial MS Unicode (36MB?) or so.

Comment: @JoopEggen even if i use Arial MS Unicode it still shows square boxes.

Comment: You could start debugging by using hard coded text `\u0b85` (Tamil a, அ) and then checking whether the database is okay, and whether the JDBC connection is okay relating to the encoding. In MySQL both have to be configured.

Comment: JoopEggen  when i use Arial MS Unicode, it supports Hindi and English only.  If i change my font to Gautami, it shows telugu properly but not hindi.  what font should i use so that it supports all the languages?

Comment: Maybe look [here](http://salrc.uchicago.edu/resources/fonts/available/hindi/). Academic sites often list fonts.